# Javascript Event Handler & While Loop Confusion

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am reading Head First AJAX and became a little confused when I came across some code in chapter 7. The chapter builds a application that randomly generates a board of letters which the user uses to create words. Once a word is created, the user clicks submit and then the word is scored. Below is the code that sets up the event handler for the word submission:

```
function initPage() {
  randomizeTiles();
  var submitDiv = document.getElementById("submit");
  while (a.nodeName == "#text") {
    a = a.nextSibling;
  }
  a.onclick = function() { 
    alert("Please click tiles to add letters and create a word."); 
  };
}
```

Here is the html for the submit button:

```
<div id="submit"><a href="#">Submit Word</a></div>
```

I am confused about the while loop used while setting up the event handler. From what I am getting this right, the while loop looks to see if there is text in the  tag. If there is, it gets the next sibling. However, what is the next sibling? there is only one node within the  tag, which is the text. Will there be anything there? Why is there a while loop here and why isnt it just an if statement?

Application Demo:
http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfajax/ch07/woggle-puzzle.html#
Application Files:
http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfajax/ch07/

Any and all input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code handles the case where you would put something else inside the div element, for example whitespace characters:

```
<div id="submit">
  <a href="#">Submit Word</a>
</div>
```

This would produce a text node before the link in some browsers.

Why there is a `while` and not just an `if` is probably just to be cautious. If some browsers puts a text node there, some browser could possibly make it more than one text node.